# How can I do the following thing without inline styling?

Tags: css

```
<div id="firstColumn" style="
    float: left; padding-right:5px; background-color:red;
">First Column</div>
<div id="SecondColumn" style="
    float: left; padding-right:5px; background-color: rgb(197, 117, 117);

">Second Column</div>
<div id="thirdColumn" style="
    float: left; padding-right:5px; background-color:blue;
">
Third Column

<div >
<div id="thirdLeftColumn" style="float:left; padding-right:5px; background-color:red;"> Third Left Column</div>
<div id="thirdRightColumn" style="float:left;background-color: rgb(168, 148, 148);">Third Right Column</div>
</div>
</div>
```

See output in 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atish_dipongkor/nj2v7/)

I want to do it using CSS rule. I don't want to use here inline styling. How can I write separate style-sheet for this.

Comment: That's not a CSS rule. That's a bunch of HTML elements with inline styles. That being said, it wouldn't be remiss to refactor all this into a separate stylesheet.

Comment: demo http://jsfiddle.net/WLVY3/

Comment: Down voter ... Care to comment. Knives in monkey's hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a `Stylesheet` to your html Page then call the `id` or `class` then copy inline CSS to the CSS file:

```
    #firstColumn{
 float: left;
 padding-right:5px;
 background-color:red;

    }
    #SecondColumn{

 float: left;
 padding-right:5px;
 background-color: rgb(197, 117, 117);
    }
    #thirdColumn{
 float: left;
 padding-right:5px;
 background-color:blue;

    }
    #thirdLeftColumn{
 float:left;
 padding-right:5px;
 background-color:red;

    }
    #thirdRightColumn{
float:left;
background-color: rgb(168, 148, 148);

    }
```

JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nj2v7/7/)

Comment: thirdColumn has no closing Div. I tried adding it. But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Take each div id and prepend it with a `#` eg. `#firstColumn`.

Then add the content of your 'style=' from each div and wrap it in `{ CONTENT HERE }` brackets.

Like so...

```
#firstColumn {
    float: left;
    padding-right:5px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Do this for all of your different div ids and save in a file with a .CSS extension.

You can use classes instead of ids to apply the same style to multiple divs. to do so do the same as you would for an id but use the following method.

```
.exampleClass {
    float:left;
    /* more attributes here */
}
```

And use a `<link>` tag to link to the file in the `<head>` of your document.

eg. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FILE_LOCATION">`

Answer (score 0):

in css, you use `#` to target an ID and `.` to target classes. 
so you would have a CSS file with:

```
#firstColumn {
  float: left; 
  padding-right:5px; 
  background-color:red;
}
#SecondColumn {
 float: left; 
 padding-right:5px; 
 background-color: rgb(197, 117, 117);
}
```

etc.
Then you can remove your `style` tag from your elements then you link your document to that css file by adding something like this in your `<head>`...

`<link href="/CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
#firstColumn, #SecondColumn, #thirdColumn, #thirdLeftColumn {
    float: left; 
    padding-right:5px;
}

#firstColumn, #thirdLeftColumn {
    background-color:red;
}

#SecondColumn {
    background-color: rgb(197, 117, 117);
}

#thirdColumn {
    background-color:blue;
}

#thirdRightColumn {
    float:left;
    background-color: rgb(168, 148, 148);
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nj2v7/3/)**

1) Use `#` to target `id`

2) Use `.` to target class

3) If they have the same styles, you can group them together and using `,` to separate the selector

4) Put this code in an external css file with name `styles.css` for example, and inside your HTML file, you can link to this external css using:

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

In this case HTML file is the same directory as this external CSS file.

Comment: as the OP is asking something very basic about how not to use inline styles, you should really put some more effort into your answer to explain what `#firstColumn, #secondColumn, #thirdColumn, #thirdLeftColumn` will do.